# How to deploy DocDokuPLM project on JBoss Wildfly10?

Tags: wildfly-10

I have cloned the docdoku-plm from this repository https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm/tree/dev
I build this project but i don't know what i have to deploy in my server , i checked in pom.xml and they have given packaging as pom
After i build the project no target file is created.
I want help how can i deploy this project in my wildfly 10 server.[This is the structure of the project and after bulid there is no target file created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhgoF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you build your project,one EAR file is generated in eplm module, you need to deploy that EAR file in wildfly.
After this follow this link https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm/wiki/Installation-Guide for configuration according to your server.
In docdoku-plm if you are using eplm project and deploying in glassfish,by default it will take EclipseLink as JPA framework and in WIldfly it is Hibernate So you have to add dependency in pom.xml or change hibernate module to eclipselink.

Comment: Hi, can you let me know how to create a project using DocdokuPlm? Are there any tutorials regarding the creation of a new project?